# Highcharts Gantt Vertical Scrollbar Missing in Full Screen Mode

Tags: highcharts, scrollbar, fullscreen, highcharts-gantt

I'm having an issue with `Highcharts Gantt 8.0.0` when viewing in `fullscreen` mode where the vertical scrollbar seems to be missing.

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('gchart-container', {
     // ... among other options, here are the related 
     // scrolling / exporting options being used

    scrollbar: {
       enabled: true
    },
    exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            // just trying a few different things here ... 
            chartOptions: {
                xAxis: [{
                    max: null
                }]
            },
            accessibility: {
                enabled: true
            },
            menuItemDefinitions: {
                "viewFullscreen" : { 'text': 'View Full Screen'},
                "downloadPDF": { 'text' : 'Download PDF'},
                "downloadPNG": { 'text' : 'Download PNG'},
                "downloadJPEG": { 'text' : 'Download JPEG'}
            },
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: ['viewFullscreen', 'separator', 'downloadPDF', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG']
                }
            }
    },
});
```

There is no issue when viewing the chart in normal mode as it's rendered in the `DOM`'s `#gchart-container` `div`  ***(notice the browser's vertical scrollbar on the right)***.

[image]

Conversely, when clicking the export button and selecting "View in Fullscreen" I have full functionality of the task hierarchy (expanding/collapsing) but vertical scrolling is disabled or removed...

[image]

Any ideas on how to enable vertical scrolling during exporting/fullscreen mode?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug. I reported it on the official Highcharts issue channel. Below is a link to follow this thread. If you need the workaround please speak up under this ticket on GH - the core developers should respond to you.

Link to issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12832